# Subdivision surface deforming geometry

Tags: rigging, subdivision-surface, shape-keys

I am trying to rig a character in Blender. While adding a shape key which will be driven by the eyelid controller, I noticed that the eyelid is deforming when the subdiv surface is on, but it remains normal when the subdiv surface is off. Can anyone help me with this?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other modifiers? If so, your subdivision surface modifier should be at the top. If that doesn't work, try removing doubles. In Blender 2.8, you do that by pressing "ALT+M" and then "B" on the keyboard. In Blender 2.9 onward, you do that by pressing "M" then "B" on the keyboard.